# Вирус майнинга закрался на сервер

Tags: php

В файлах php появился посторонний код и в папки mod-tmo создаются файлы php*************** которые загружат cpu на до 100%

Может кто знает иешение данного вопроса? А то как-то не очень)

Comment: Решение - провести анализ инцидента и восстановить сайт с резервной копии.

Comment: Была такая же штука, корней и причин не нашли

Comment: устал но закрыл дыры, правда пришлось долбить айболитом и прочими пару недель=)